# Run $scope function when input field modifies?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an input field, where you can specify min number of reviews. I also have a function that updates data that `ng-repeat` populates and create the table. But what I need is, when you type some number into input field this function of mine, runs automatically and changes data which means that my table is up-to-date automatically. It is some sort of two-way binding. (I don't want to use filter directly on my `ng-repeat`, filters in angular run very frequently and decrease performance)

Here is my input field:

```
<label>Reviews Min: <input type="number" ng-init="revNum=30" class="form-control review-input" min="0" step="10" ng-model="filterValues.revNum" /></label>
```

Here is my `ng-repeat`:

```
 ng-repeat="car in sortedCarList"
```

And here is the function:

```
$scope.formattedTable = function(index){
    $scope.initCarList(index);
    $scope.sortedCarList = [];
    var carlistLength = $scope.carList.length;
    for (var i=0;i<carlistLength;i++){   // just checks every row if values passes user requirements like: min number of review and price range
        var rowBool = $scope.tableFilter($scope.carList[i]);
        if (rowBool){
            $scope.sortedCarList.push($scope.carList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Have you tried using [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive to run a specific function every time the input changes.

```
<label>Reviews Min: <input type="number" ng-init="revNum=30" class="form-control review-input" min="0" step="10" ng-model="filterValues.revNum" ng-change="formattedTable()" /></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

there a two methodes:

a) Watcher:

```
$scope.$watch('filterValues.revNum', function() {
    $scope.formattedTable();
});
```

b) ng-change:

```
<label>Reviews Min: <input type="number" ng-init="revNum=30" class="form-control review-input" min="0" step="10" ng-model="filterValues.revNum" ng-change="formattedTable()"/></label>
```